# why is xcode 5 not finding a header file for newrelic enough though the library is there?

Tags: xcode, gcc, static-libraries, xcodebuild

I added the newrelic objective-c library to my project and it worked fine.  Compiled no issues.  Checked everything into git and did a git pull from another machine.  It compiles fine on that machine too.

But on our QA machine it gives the error

```
'NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent.h' file not found.
```

The QA machine is also using xcode 5 but there must be some difference I can't figure out.

[image: xcode error]

The library is there under Frameworks.  The header file is there I can see it!  Any ideas?

One small difference I noticed is on my machine in the finder the icon for the library is:

[image: icon]

A lego peice.  But on the QA machine it's just a normal folder icon.

Comment: i'm experiencing the same issue. were you ever able to resolve this? i added new relic via `cocoapods` though.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the framework? If you added it to the Build Phases pane, the headers dir should have been added to the header search path.

I have found that for whatever reason, when I add a third party framework, it works if you make a folder, not just a group, and then put the framework file in there. So the flow would be:

1. Make a group called thirdparty
2. Go to the inspector and make sure that the checkbox is checked for it to use a folder, and that there is a real folder there
3. Add it on the build phases pane, pointing to it in the folder

Then try and use an import. If it doesn't work, double check that the header dir was added. I did this many times with OCHamcrest.